# 8/16 bit microprocessor for hobby project

Tags: memory, cpu

I'm evaluating different processors for a small hoby project. My first choice was the Z80 but it seem to be hard to come by nowdays.

Whats left for us that wants an 8/16 bit CPU clocked on 10-20 Mhz with an external memory bus ?

Comment: Why do you need external memory?

Comment: Havent found something with 512 KB internal memory.....

Comment: Do you need 512kB of Flash or SRAM?

Comment: I need 256-512 KB SRAM to realize this project

Comment: Yup, that's basically a mandate for external memory.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you should let go of the idea that for small hobby projects 8-bitters are always the best solution. Nowadays 32-bitters, esp. ARM, are everywhere and they have become serious competitors for the often older 8/16-bit parts, both price-wise and toolchain-wise.
Besides, in your comment you mention 512 KB internal memory, and you won't find that easily on pure 8-bitters; they tend to have a 16-bit address bus which means 64 KB maximum.
If you think an ARM may suit you, you may have a look at [mbed](http://mbed.org/):

> "This mbed Microcontroller is based on the NXP LPC1768 with an ARM Cortex-M3 Core running at 96MHz, **512KB FLASH**, 64KB RAM and lots of interfaces including Ethernet, USB Device and Host, CAN, SPI, I2C and other I/O."

Comment: Maybe, I just vary that it will be a problem further on when I want to design my own PCB, higher freq. means problems on the PCB.

Comment: @Z-roar: You can clock it at 10-20 MHz (or even lower, approaching DC) if you're uncomfortable with a 96 MHz design.

Comment: Er, I thought you meant 512 KB of Flash, not RAM. Like reemrevnivek says you'll want a controller with external memory.

Answer (score 4):

Interfacing with an external memory module is best done with a hardware peripheral known as an External Memory Interface (tricky, huh?).  An External Bus Interface can also be adapted for the purpose.  These peripherals are abbreviated EMI/EBI on manufacturer and distributor parametric search engines.

Using Digikey's parametric search, for example, I note 209 different parts have an EMI or EBI (with a few other distinctions, like onboard Flash, solderable packages, and less-than-reel quantities) .  The following is a selection of the more well-known processors from that set:

- AVR Xmega
- Arm Cortex-M0
- Arm Cortex-M3
- Arm 7
- Arm 9
- Coldfire
- STMicroelectronics   ST9
- ZNEO (Zilog 16-bit successor to Z80)
- 8051

Comment: <Subjective>I recommend the Arm Cortex-M0, Cortex-M3, and Arm 7 series from that set as the best-documented,  most beginner-friendly, and most available selection. </Subjective>

Comment: An SPI memory (RAM or flash) chip can fetch an arbitrary byte of memory in about six microseconds or less, and succeeding bytes in less than a microsecond each.  Some applications require memory access at speeds which can't be achieved via SPI flash, but for a hobby-level project wiring up four wires for an SPI memory chip would seem much more appealing than wiring dozens of wires for a parallel memory interface.

Comment: @supercat - Huh, I didn't know they made serial SRAM.  Neat!  It looks like you'd have to use 2 chips to get 512 kB, but that's still probably preferable to the parallel interface.

Answer (score 3):

ez80 series is available both as microprocessor and microcontroller. It can address 24 bits of memory and comes with plenty of peripherals. It's compatible with Z80.

Here are the microprocessors (but the microcontrollers have memory busses too and are actually cheaper):

http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Cat=2556260&k=ez80

They also have development boards.

Answer (score 2):

There are some PICs with external memory interfaces that can address up to 2 Mbytes (code or data):

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00869b.pdf

Answer (score 2):

ARM is the way to go, lots of various sizes of ram vs flash.  Every combination of size speed, power, etc.  Mainstream tools, etc.  For an external memory interface Cirrus has ARM products.

When you say 512KB I assume that is just for data and you need flash and/or ram for the program as well.  Depending on the instruction set the amount of program space can/will vary dramatically.

The next question is how fast do you need to get at this memory, you could probably go with some spi or i2c and use pretty much any micro if it doesnt have to be lightnight fast.  Granted if you were looking for a handful of megahertz 8/16 processor then for the same price you can get into a 50-80mhz arm and probably get similar memory speeds to the 8/16 micro with a serial memory.

For the price of an arduino you can get a GameboyAdvance, 17mhz ARM7 256K plus 32M of onboard memory, then for a little over half the price of a second arduino 512KB of ram, plus another 16KB plus 32MB of flash.  You get a display and serial port as a freebie...

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of application it boils down to two main product lines: PIC (Microchip) and AVR (Atmel). Both have many models from the very basic (the ATTiny13, for instance, is 10 MHz and costs about $1) to the quite sophisticated (barely overlapping the entry level ARMs). All of them support SPI/I2C via software or hardware, and those with enough interface pins can be connected to external memory. For those who don't, there's also the option of using a SPI memory. Also there are many options of tools for development & debugging, many of them free or low-cost.